# How to position the field in Alfresco form?

Tags: alfresco

I have a Surf form (Alfresco) and several sets in that. I have several fields in one set and need to position the field relative others fields in the set. Please tell me how to do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use *`<set>`* under `<appearance>` section, to logically group the fields.

In the below example, text fields will be displayed in a different section, number fields in a different section and date fields in a different section.

To use nested grouping , you can use parent `attribute`.

```
    <config evaluator="model-type" condition="my:example">
   <forms>
      <form>
         <field-visibility>
            <show id="cm:name" />
            <show id="my:text" />
            <show id="my:mltext" />
            <show id="my:boolean" />
            <show id="my:int" />
            <show id="my:long" />
            <show id="my:double" />
            <show id="my:float" />
         </field-visibility>
         <appearance>
            <set id="builtin" appearance="fieldset" label="Built In" />
            <set id="custom" appearance="fieldset" label="Custom Data" />
            <set id="text" parent="custom" appearance="panel" label="Text" />
            <set id="number" parent="custom" appearance="panel" label="Numbers" />

            <field id="cm:name" set="builtin" />

            <field id="my:text" set="text" />
            <field id="my:mltext" set="text" />
            <field id="my:boolean" set="text" />

            <field id="my:int" set="number" />
            <field id="my:long" set="number" />
            <field id="my:double" set="number" />
            <field id="my:float" set="number" />
         </appearance>
      </form>
   </forms>
</config>
```

For more information, please refer the below link.

https://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/forms-grouping-fields.html

Hope this helps you.

Comment: What about share/src/main/resources/alfresco/web-extension/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/form/tabbed.ftl ? it seems it contains some formatting logic